# What are the best practices to handling app suspensions and "Too many simultaneous connections were made to this Gmail account" error for Mailcore2?

Tags: ios, imap, mailcore2

One problem I encountered is if the user manually terminates the app from the background process, relaunches a fresh instance of the app and continues to do this several times, it will open up multiple IMAP sessions with Google which causes the "too many simultaneous connection" error.

What do you recommend to the solution here to be? I don't believe Mailcore2 auto disconnects on suspension, correct?

I can always call "disconnect" explicitly when the app moves to the background, but I would still like to keep a open connection for background fetch... The problem is Apple does not allow a developer to know whether the app is simply moved to the background or suspended.

Comment: There's a disconnect operation on IMAPSession. Have you tried that? I don't think you're able to keep the connection to fetch in the background. Apple would disallow it.

Comment: Apple does not allow that because it's not supposed to make a difference — you're supposed to do the right thing based on user actions. If the user terminates and you're carrying out a background fetch, that's something. If the user terminates and you're not doing anything, the user hasn't given you any reason to keep the connection open.